# ASP MVC 4 multilanguage route switch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, multilingual

I have a multilanguage MVC applications where I define the routes as follows (the default route is `/{lang}/{controller}/{action}`):

```
routes.MapRoute("FAQEN", "{lang}/frequently-asked-questions/", new { controller = "Home", action = "FAQ", lang = "en" }, new { lang = "en" });
routes.MapRoute("FAQNL", "{lang}/veelgestelde-vragen/", new { controller = "Home", action = "FAQ", lang = "nl" }, new { lang = "nl" });
```

This results in the urls

- mywebsite.com/en/frequently-asked-questions
- mywebsite.com/nl/veelgestelde-vragen

In the footer of my website there is a language switch that works like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Language", "Home", new { returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery })">Switch language</a>
```

So when someone clicks this action to go from EN to NL the returnUrl is for example `/en/frequently-asked-questions`. Currently I translate the `frequently-asked-questions` string to `veelgestelde-vragen` using an array with string translations. The problem with this solution is that I have to maintain two objects of merely the same content; the routes and the array with string translations. Is there an easier way to solve this problem? For instance, is it possible to convert the string `/en/frequently-asked-questions` back to the `FAQ` action in the `HomeController`, and then get the NL route for the `FAQ` action?

Answer (score 0):

in your home/language action you need to set current culture.

You may take a look at this link
"[To set the culture and UI culture for an ASP.NET Web page programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.ASPX)"

Comment: For MVC based approach see if this link helps : http://adamyan.blogspot.in/2010/07/addition-to-aspnet-mvc-localization.html

Comment: Thanks Vishnoo Rath, I'll take a look at the source. Maybe I can find something helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this blogpost](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-%28ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms%29.aspx). You won't need the language part in the controller and you can use resx files to translate the urls.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is not really to have different routes per language, but linking from one language to another (switch the language) by translating the referer url(`Request.Url.PathAndQuery`).